# Переадресация через .htaccess для разделов

Tags: .htaccess, apache, редирект

Как сделать переадресацию через .htaccess для адресов, начинающихся с `site.com/div/sub/` на `site.com/sub/`

Пример: `site.com/div/sub/foo/ -> site.com/sub/foo/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, вот так должно работать

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^div/(.+)$ /$1
```

Comment: Не получается...

Comment: Ваш .htaccess выглядит так, как сейчас у меня в ответе, и не работает?

Comment: С флагом R заработало, видимо, дальнейшие преобразования в .htaccess работали.

Comment: да, вполне возможно